# replaceWith() for an option with a value for a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

i have a domain class A which consist of a combobox with dog and cat as options and i also hav e a textbox as animal when i choose dog i want to replace animal text box with dog and when i select cat i want to replace the dog textbox with cat, i used jquery replaceWith() but it replace for first select that is from animal->dog, when i try to select cat its not changing from dog -> cat

```
function showReadonly(valobj) {
    var dogtr = '<tr><g:field name="dog" type=""value="${fieldValue(bean:AInstance, field: '
    dog ')}"/></tr>'
    var cattr = '<tr><g:field name="cat" type=""value="${fieldValue(bean:AInstance, field: '
    cat ')}"/></tr>'
    if (valobj == "dog") {
        jQuery("td#someid").parent().replaceWith(dogtr);
    } else if (valobj == "cat") {
        jQuery("td#someid").parent().replaceWith(cattr);
    }
}
```

can anyone suggest me a solution for this

Comment: Please post a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net .

Comment: i found why its not working, i forgot to pass ids for dogtr and cattr, after passing that it works fine var dogtr = '<tr><g:field name="dog" id="someid" type=""value="${fieldValue(bean:AInstance, field: '
    dog ')}"/></tr>'
    var cattr = '<tr><g:field name="cat" id="someid" type=""value="${fieldValue(bean:AInstance, field: '
    cat ')}"/></tr>'